# I am implementing crud application using angular and firebase realtime database.pass data in url e.g http://localhost:4200/customer/{key value}

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
<form class="form-inline border-primary mb-3 mt-4 mx-4" style="max-width: 40rem;">
    <input class="form-control" name="searchInput" placeholder="Search" #searchInput="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="searchText" style="width: 80%;">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="searchText=''">X</button>
</form>

<div class="card border-primary mb-3 mt-4 mx-4" style="max-width: 80rem;">

    <div class="card-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered mt-4 ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email</th>
                    <th scope="col">Mobile No</th>
                    <th scope="col">Location</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody *ngFor="let customer of customerArray">
                <tr class="table-default mt-3" *ngIf="filterCondition(customer)">
                    <td>{{customer.fullName}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.mobile}}</td>
                    <td>{{customer.location}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" (click)="customerService.populateForm(customer)" routerLink='/customer'>Edit</button>&nbsp;
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="onDelete(customer.$key)">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This is a customer list component. After clicking on edit the form populate to a customer component, so I need a key of the particular record in URL while editing.

how can i pass key value in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a route with parameters like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/customer/:key', component: YourCustomerComponent}
];
```

On button click call function in ts file 
and navigate it by using below line

```
this.router.navigate(['/customer', key]);
```

OR

In template you can also do

```
<button  [routerLink]="['/customer', key]">clickB</button>
```

In your case you have to create button with click event in template(html) like

```
<button (click)="navigateToEdit()">clickB</button>
```

and in ts file handle button click

```
navigateToEdit(){
// first get data to edit or navigate first than get data and bind that data into html

this.router.navigate(['/customer', key]);
}
```

Then you can read it with:

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['key'];
    });
}
```

Hope this will help you

let me know if any issue

thanks

Comment: @Triveni Mali , look at above answer i have updated let me know..

Comment: I have replaced in answer `params['id ']` to `params['key']`

Comment: edited answer, and one more thing you have to pass value into key where we are navigating